# TypeError: the first argument must be callable when calling tensorflow optimizer `apply_gradients`

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, reinforcement-learning

I hope someone can help me resolve this issue which has been driving me crazy for days. I am building something somehow inspired to [this](https://keras.io/examples/rl/actor_critic_cartpole/) keras example. I am trying to manually calculate the gradient of a network but I can't figure out what I am doing wrong. Here is the model definition

```
inputs = layers.Input(shape=(state_dim,))
layer1 = layers.Dense(l1_dim, activation="relu")(inputs)
ayer2 = layers.Dense(l2_dim, activation="relu")(layer1)
action = layers.Dense(num_actions, activation="softmax")(layer2)
critic = layers.Dense(1, activation=None)(layer2)

model = keras.Model(inputs=inputs, outputs=[critic, action])
# model.compile(optimizer=keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=learning_rate))
optimizer = keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=learning_rate)
```

then I have my training loop, given set (state, action, reward, terminal, state_):

```
state = tf.convert_to_tensor([state], dtype=tf.float32)
state_ = tf.convert_to_tensor([state_], dtype=tf.float32)
reward = tf.convert_to_tensor(reward, dtype=tf.float32)  # not fed to NN
with tf.GradientTape(persistent=True) as tape:
     state_value, probs = model(state)
     state_value_, _ = model(state_)
     state_value = tf.squeeze(state_value)
     state_value_ = tf.squeeze(state_value_)

     action_probs = tfp.distributions.Categorical(probs=probs)
     log_prob = action_probs.log_prob(action)

     delta = reward + self.gamma * state_value_ * (1 - int(terminal)) - state_value
     actor_loss = -log_prob * delta
     critic_loss = delta ** 2
     total_loss = actor_loss + critic_loss

gradient = tape.gradient(total_loss, model.trainable_variables)
optimizer.apply_gradients(zip(gradient, model.trainable_variables))
```

However on my last line of code, when calling `optimizer.apply_gradients` I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/maccheroni/.virtualenvs/rl_gym/lib/python3.9/site-packages/keras/optimizer_v2/optimizer_v2.py", line 639, in apply_gradients
    self._create_all_weights(var_list)
  File "/Users/maccheroni/.virtualenvs/rl_gym/lib/python3.9/site-packages/keras/optimizer_v2/optimizer_v2.py", line 829, in _create_all_weights
    self._create_hypers()
  File "/Users/maccheroni/.virtualenvs/rl_gym/lib/python3.9/site-packages/keras/optimizer_v2/optimizer_v2.py", line 977, in _create_hypers
    self._hyper[name] = self.add_weight(
  File "/Users/maccheroni/.virtualenvs/rl_gym/lib/python3.9/site-packages/keras/optimizer_v2/optimizer_v2.py", line 1192, in add_weight
    variable = self._add_variable_with_custom_getter(
  File "/Users/maccheroni/.virtualenvs/rl_gym/lib/python3.9/site-packages/tensorflow/python/training/tracking/base.py", line 816, in _add_variable_with_custom_getter
    new_variable = getter(
  File "/Users/maccheroni/.virtualenvs/rl_gym/lib/python3.9/site-packages/keras/engine/base_layer_utils.py", line 106, in make_variable
    init_val = functools.partial(initializer, shape, dtype=dtype)
TypeError: the first argument must be callable
```

and I really don't understand why, because I have read so many tutorials, followed so many examples and they seem all to use this function in this way.

Comment: does your seccond code example has the same indention as  in your code? tape.gradient() and optimizer.apply_gradients() must be outside the tf.GradientTape scope.

Comment: very good point! to be honest i tried both ways and the error is the same, but i asked myself the same question. If you look at the keras example i inspired my code from the `apply_gradients` function is within the scope, which i found strange. To be honest i am not expert enough to understand the difference. Any clarification why should be outside would be actually aslo appreciated.

Comment: the with statement combines two functions that occur together which have some code in between e.g. starting to save gradients and stoping to save gradients. Once you you exit the with-block, no further gradients are recorded and you can acces the final tape. Here is an intro to the with-statement: https://preshing.com/20110920/the-python-with-statement-by-example/. After that you can check the implementation of GradientTape and find some similarities to the guide :) :https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/v2.7.0/tensorflow/python/eager/backprop.py#L741-L1366

Comment: thank for the info. However I have tried to put the tape_gradients outside the with statement and unfortunately i get the same error. I have edited my question so i won't get this pointed out again. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I also had the same error and found the solution. In my case, the initialization of the optimizer:

```
optimizer = keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=learning_rate)
```

was using the variable `learning_rate` which was `None`. initializting with a number or simply:

```
optimizer = keras.optimizers.Adam()
```

solved the issue.
In your case, it is not clear, what `learning_rate` is but you might check this out.